# Formatting Date in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, string-formatting

I am having TimeStamp as a String input. I'll have to convert it into a String of another format.

For example:

`input string : 2013-12-23 20:59:15.0`

`output string: 2013/12/23`

So I wrote a small Java program to do that :

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
    {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.SS");
        String x ="2013-12-23 20:59:15.0";

        Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(x);

        Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

        String y = formatter.format(parsedDate);

        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

Now no matter what the input is, the month value always comes back to be `1`.

For example :

`input string : 2013-12-23 20:59:15.0`

`output string: 2013/01/23`

Another example :

`input string : 2012-05-23 20:59:15.0`

`output string: 2012/01/23`

**Am I missing something here ?**

Comment: Always read the javadoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yyyy-mm-dd` should be `yyyy-MM-dd`

Basically, you converting the month element to minutes.

> m Minute in hour  Number  30
>   M Month in year   Month   July; Jul; 07

Take a look at [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SS");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Dateformat

{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws ParseException
    {
        String oldstring = "2013-11-15 00:00:00.0";

        java.util.Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse(oldstring);

        String newstring = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);

        System.out.println(newstring);

    }

}
```

**output**

2013-11-15